# Create MySQL view with an extra calculated field in table

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I am using python and MySQLdb module. I have a table that looks like this;

```
TableA
------
id
latest_time_seen
```

The format of `latest_time_seen` is `2014-02-05 00:00:50`

From `TableA`, I would like to create a view on mysql that is similar to `TableA` and the only difference is that it contains an extra calculated field called `secs_diff`.

`secs_diff` is equal to the number of seconds difference between current time and `latest_time_seen`.

The output table will look something like this;

```
OutputTable
-----------
id
latest_time_seen
secs_diff
```

I doubt if I have problems writing a python function to calculate secs_diff. But I am stuck at how to integrate this function into a MySQL query that generates a view that looks like `OutputTable`.

How can such a view be generated using python and MySQLdb module? Or would it be better to use a temporary table? It will be better if such a view can be generated purely from a MySQL query. But I am not sure if MySQL query is flexible enough to calculate the time difference.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do with pure MySQL,

try using this query

```
select *,TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), latest_time_seen)) as secs_diff from tbl
```

see [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13e62/2)